# List specific files from a directory

Tags: windows, command-line, ffmpeg, batch, utorrent

I can't list a specific files of a directory passed as argument to a batch file.

The problem I am facing is that the pipe "|" character is not recognized, I used it to circumvent the `dir` command limitations that it can

```
dir /b *.avi *.mp4 *.mkv
```

within a directory, but as I am creating this batch file to execute after uTorrent, I need to pass the directory as argument.

Globally, what I am trying to do is to automatically convert files downloaded by uTorrent to AAC audio.

Here's the batch files content:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i IN ('dir %1 /b /A-D | findstr /I (avi mp4 mkv)') DO ffmpeg -i "%%~fi" -c:v copy -c:a aac -ac 2 "%%~di%%~pi%%~ni_aac%%~xi" 
PAUSE
```

Answer (score 1):

#### The pipe `|` character is not recognized

You would need to escape it as follows:

```
^|
```

There are some additional errors in your code:

- Piping to `findstr /I (avi mp4 mkv)` doesn't work as `findstr` doesn't work that way. You don't need `findstr` or piping anyway.
- If it did work you would have to also escape `(` and `)`.
- `"%%~di%%~pi%%~ni_aac%%~xi"` doesn't give the output file the extension `.acc`

Try the following:

```
pushd %1
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%i IN (`dir /b *.avi *.mp4 *.mkv`) DO (
  echo ffmpeg -i "%%~fi" -c:v copy -c:a aac -ac 2 "%%~di%%~pi%%~ni.aac" 
  )
PAUSE
popd
```

Remove the `echo` if you are happy with the modified `ffmpeg` command.

> `^`  Escape character.
>
> Adding the escape character before a command symbol allows it to be
>   treated as ordinary text.
>
> When piping or redirecting any of these characters you should prefix
>   with the escape character: `& \ < > ^ |`
>
> eg `^\  ^&  ^|  ^>  ^<  ^^`

Source [Quotes, Escape Characters, Delimiters - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [For - Loop through command output - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)
- [Pushd - change directory/folder - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html)
- [Popd - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/popd.html)
- [Quotes, Escape Characters, Delimiters - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)

PAUSE

Comment: No, it does not work: it says `') was expected`

Comment: Answer updated.